# Getting an image to show based on a checkbox:checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have created a function `fadeBoolToggle` which fades in and out based on the boolean value.

I added code to make my checkboxes act like radio buttons. Then I created a variable to set a limit to 1 `limitCal` (My real code requires checkboxes, so radio inputs could not be used). This is working fine.

What isn't working is that I can't figure out how to get my image to not show when the input is no longer selected.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function (bool) {
        return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
    }
var limitCal = 1;
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  $('.calendar-check').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
  if (!this.checked || $('.calendar-check:checked').length <= limitCal) {
    $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(this.checked);
  }
});
```

```css
.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-2year" class="package-check-toggle">
      <h4 class="calendar-box-title">A</h4>
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-whiteboard" class="package-check-toggle">
       <h4 class="calendar-box-title">B</h4>
       <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-glance" class="package-check-toggle">
      <h4 class="calendar-box-title">C</h4>
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-glance">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.checked` will always be `true`, because you just set it to `true`. So you show the current checkbox's image, but there is no code to hide the previously checked checkbox's image.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not sure what else to set it to. If I do `.fadeBoolToggle(':checked');` It still does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only ever calls `.fadeBoolToggle()` on the just-checked checkbox's corresponding image. At that point `this.checked` is `true`, so the current image fades in as desired. But you have no code to fade out the image from the previously checked box.

Here's one way to do that, simplifying your code along the way (notice you don't really need your `.fadeBoolToggle()` for this code, because its argument is always hardcoded so you could just use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`, but I've left your function in place):

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function (bool) {
        return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
    }
var limitCal = 1;
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  $('.calendar-check').not(this) // select the *other* checkboxes
    .prop('checked', false)      // uncheck them
    .closest('.product-wrap')    // select their wrappers
    .find('.checkmark-img')      // find their images
    .fadeBoolToggle(false);      // fade them out
  this.checked = true;           // check current checkbox
  $(this).closest('.product-wrap') // get current one's wrapper
    .find('.checkmark-img')      // find current image
    .fadeBoolToggle(true);       // fade it in
});
```

```css
.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-2year" class="package-check-toggle">
      <h4 class="calendar-box-title">A</h4>
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-whiteboard" class="package-check-toggle">
       <h4 class="calendar-box-title">B</h4>
       <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-glance" class="package-check-toggle">
      <h4 class="calendar-box-title">C</h4>
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-glance">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming you don't want to be able to uncheck all of the checkboxes (so they behave like radios).

Comment: Thank you for the edit explaining the sequence! This is perfect. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I tried doing this for another section, but it won't display the image at all? Any idea why? https://jsfiddle.net/4ckjy7nb/

Comment: You forgot to include your fade function. (You should have seen an error in the console.) I didn't have the patience to copy your function into the fiddle, but here it works with standard fade functions: https://jsfiddle.net/4ckjy7nb/2/

Comment: Gotcha. I see that now within the example. I am at a loss for what to do in my actual code. I have implemented it exactly as the example. I even created a fiddle and it works properly, but within my code it just doesn't display. I made a codepen and shaved off a lot of the code. I left some in it to ensure the effect works. If you could look at it I would really appreciate it. I've been looking at it for two hours and can't figure it out. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWapOq

Comment: The `change` handler on the Cards/Years section didn't work because you were binding the handler to elements that didn't exist yet - those elements are added dynamically. Uses a delegated event handler bound to the container that does exist on page load, i.e., change `$('.tp-structure-check').on('change', function () {...` to be `$('#tp-frequency').on('change','.tp-structure-check', function () { ...` (Seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmQgEX)

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of delegated events, so this definitely helped. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I have slimmed your code a little bit. Check if it's fine for you.

Do you want to be able to *uncheck* the checked checkbox?

```js
$('.calendar-check').on('change', function(){
  $('.calendar-check').parent().find('img').fadeOut();
  $('.calendar-check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  $('.calendar-check:checked').parent().find('img').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-2year" class="package-check-toggle">
      <h4 class="calendar-box-title">A</h4>
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-whiteboard" class="package-check-toggle">
       <h4 class="calendar-box-title">B</h4>
       <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-box">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="cal-glance" class="package-check-toggle">
      <h4 class="calendar-box-title">C</h4>
      <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-glance">
  </div>
</div>
```